# is there a simple way to check wether a mp4 file is valid?

Tags: java, mp4

In my servlet application (that serves android apps) i allow to upload mp4 files. Now i am paranoic and i want to validate uploaded videos by looking at the content not only by checking the content type and the extension since : the content type can be easily spoofed and if someone finds some bugs in standard android player it can also upload a .mp4 malware that can exploit my users applications.

So im just looking for a simple way to check if the uploaded files have at least a valid mp4 structure.
Im also very interested in performance so i also dont like to parse the whole file like i were doing when i want to play it.

Is there any way to do that ?
Thanks

Comment: http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/javadoc/net/sourceforge/jaad/mp4/MP4Container.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is: no, there is not really a simple way to do it. You could use a 3rd party java library that knows how to decode/intepret a valid .mp4 file such as the one zod mentioned, but (in my mind) that falls outside of the 'simple category'.

Another option would be to check to see if valid .mp4 metadata is available in the file, but because the metadata is not required, this isn't really a good solution.

Comment: thanks for replying!
Anyway since i'll have some "official" apps that will load those files I can force them to add metadata. So the two new questions are: is metadata checking enough? in other words, the successful access to metadata implies a well formed mp4?
And the second question is: is metadata access simple and fast enough? (with simple and fast I mean that does not add a significant overhead with respect to the copying of a file of about 1-5MB)

Comment: Yes, I do believe that it'd be fast enough to meet your needs (I haven't dealt with audio files in a while) Although valid metadata does NOT imply valid .mp4, if you added your own metadata that had a pre-determined format (or a flag!) the odds of someone using malware and copying that goes down SIGNIFICANTLY. (people are inherently lazy in my opinion). That would be my suggestion.